# Merge two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database

Table A:

```
Start_Date    End_date      Ad_name       Amount Spent
2022-09-01   2022-09-30    Facebook -       2.5
2022-09-01   2022-09-30    Facebook -      24.5
2022-09-01   2022-09-30    twitter -       12.5
```

Table B:

```
Start_Date    End_date      Ad_name       Amount Spent
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    instagram -      52.5
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    Facebook -      124.5
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    twitter -        30
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    twitter -        60
```

I want to get to get an output of Table C

```
Start_Date    End_date      Ad_name       Amount Spent
2022-09-01   2022-09-30    Facebook -        2.5
2022-09-01   2022-09-30    Facebook -       24.5
2022-09-01   2022-09-30    twitter -        12.5
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    instagram -      52.5
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    Facebook -      124.5
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    twitter -        30
2022-08-01   2022-08-30    twitter -        60
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Your question is hard to read, check the help section on how to create a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, this is the explanation of MERGE from MS Learn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

Because your tables have the same structure you ca use a simple `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B;
```

[sql editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/d0137a6047466ae6317d7a6ccf289de8/)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you need [UNION ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B
```